# Integral of: $y^{2}.\exp(-(y^{2})/2)$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I need to calculate this integral of $\int_{0}^{\infty} y^{2} \exp(-y^{2}/2) dy$

I started doing by parts: $u = y$, $v= - \exp(-y^{2}/2)$, $du=dv$ and $dv=-y \exp(- y^{2}/2)$

So, $-y \exp(-y^{2}/2) + \int_{0}^{\infty} \exp(-y^{2}/2)$. $-y \exp(-y^{2}/2) =0$ when integrating in $(0, \infty)$ and I will have the integration of :$\int_{0}^{\infty} \exp(-y^{2}/2)$

From now on I cant move.

Any help?

Many Thanks

Comment: I am probably making a mistake in integratio by parts. Did see something wrong? @greelious

Comment: @greelious There is a closed form with its limits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick for these kinds of integral is to manipulate it into the form of the Gamma Function$$\Gamma(z)=\int\limits_0^{\infty}\mathrm dt\, t^{z-1}e^{-t}$$To reduce your integral, label it as $\mathfrak{I}$ and let $t=\frac 12y^2$. Therefore $\mathrm dt=y\,\mathrm dy$ and $y=\sqrt{2t}$

$$\begin{align*}\mathfrak{I} & =\int\limits_0^{\infty}\mathrm dt\,\sqrt{2t}\, e^{-t}\\ & =\sqrt2\int\limits_0^{\infty}\mathrm dt\, t^{1/2}e^{-t}\\ & =\sqrt2\Gamma\left(\frac 32\right)\end{align*}$$

Since

$$\Gamma\left(\frac 32\right)=\frac {\sqrt\pi}2$$Thus$$\int\limits_0^{\infty}\mathrm dt\, t^{z-1}e^{-t}\color{blue}{=\sqrt{\frac {\pi}2}}$$

Comment: I couldnt imagine that.

Answer (score 0):

the final integral you arrived at involves the limit for error function. you can either look for the properties of error function, or prove it by extending the integtal into the squareroot of a double integral and then transform into polar coordinates.